# Preventing duplicate organisations being created

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I wonder if anyone can help me with what I'm missing re duplicate contacts.

We have a profile form which also creates a wordpress account - it asks only for first & last name, email, username and password.

Once registered and logged in, we have a separate profile form that asks users for more information, including their current employer. We ask only the employer name, and for no other information about that organisation.

If two separate users enter exactly the same current employer name, two organisation records are created.

Looking at the profile settings I'm actually surprised this is happening, because the de-dupe option that we have set is:

[image: Profile Settings]

The unsupervised dedupe rule for organisations is:

[image: Unsupervised de-dupe rule]

We also have the extension 'The the' installed as it's common in our sector for people to register their company with and without a 'the' at the start.

I'm guessing the profile settings don't influence any *related* contacts that may be created, which is why people are being able to create duplicate employer/organisation records... But any thoughts on why the unsupervised de-dupe rule is not working in the way I would expect?

Especially when, if we run the de-dupe manually, the unsupervised rule DOES spot the duplicates!

[image: Manual run]

I'm sure this is something basic that I'm getting wrong, but I just can't fathom it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set as Organisation name instead sort name.

[image]

Comment: Hi,, that's how we started out (we changed it to Sort Name after installing The The) but I'll give it another go and report back :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out https://civicrm.org/extensions/public-autocomplete-of-organisation-names but of course this means the list of Orgs that you allow to show become 'public' in a sense, and hence may have security concerns

Comment: Thanks Pete - I should've said we also already have that extension installed. It's great, but there are still some duplicates slipping through